# Running an interactive application with elevated privileges within a Standard User

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, elevated-privileges

I am trying to open an interactive application running under the SYSTEM account within the desktop of a standard user(The interactive application has Administrative Privileges). I know this is generally not possible due to session isolation etc. However, I have witnessed applications which does so.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

using namespace std;

STARTUPINFO GetStartupInfo()
{
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));

    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    startupInfo.lpDesktop = const_cast<LPWSTR>(_T("Winsta0\\default"));
    startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;


    return startupInfo;
}

HANDLE SetInfoOnToken(HANDLE existingToken)
{
    HANDLE duplicateToken;
    DWORD TokenSessionId = 1;
    DuplicateTokenEx(existingToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, nullptr, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL::SecurityIdentification, TOKEN_TYPE::TokenPrimary, &duplicateToken);
    SetTokenInformation(duplicateToken, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenSessionId, &TokenSessionId, sizeof(TokenSessionId));

    return duplicateToken;
}

bool SetTcbPrivilege(HANDLE hToken)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;
    bool success = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, _T("SeTcbPrivilege"), &luid);

    if (!success) {
        wcout << GetLastError();
        return false;
    }
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(&hToken,FALSE,&tp,sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,(PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED) return false;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[], TCHAR *envp[])
{
    wstring processName = _T("notepad.exe");
    TCHAR* name = (wchar_t*)processName.c_str();
    DWORD sessionId = 0;
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = GetStartupInfo();
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
    HANDLE processHandle = nullptr;
    ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));
    HANDLE hToken = GetCurrentProcessToken();
    SetTcbPrivilege(hToken);
    hToken = SetInfoOnToken(hToken);
    bool success = false;

    success = CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, nullptr, name, nullptr, nullptr, false, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &startupInfo, &processInformation);

    if (success)
    {
        wcout << "Process started.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << "There was a problem starting the process.\n";
        wcout << GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }

    CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works perfectly when started normally. But when run under the SYSTEM account, it does not show the notepad window (I am aware it generally shouldn't, but that is the limitation I am trying to overcome and have seen certain apps doing so). There is however a process for notepad listed in the Task Manager.

What am I missing in the code which returns this unexpected behavior ? I am left with less samples of such scenario, so please provide any suggestions on this.

EDIT:

At this point the process does not run an leaves an ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE error. What am I doing incorrect ? Please suggest.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an application that does this? Off the top of my head, I'd imagine that this is the sort of thing that would happen if a service running under SYSTEM started a process on an interactive desktop. A common question asked here is how a service can started a process on an interactive desktop with a user other than SYSTEM.

Comment: Hi, an example I can provide you is the Nvidia Display Container (ie., NVDisplay.Container). This is the only solid demo I have of an application doing this.

Comment: you need use `CreateProcessAsUserW` and get token of interactive session

Comment: Assuming the current process is running as SYSTEM, then this is relatively easy since you don't have to do anything tricky to get a SYSTEM token. It's also relatively easy because SYSTEM is granted full access to the session's "WinSta0" window station and "Default" desktop. Just duplicate the process token, set the `TokenSessionId` to the desired interactive session (requires SeTcbPrivilege to be enabled), and create the process via `CreateProcessAsUserW`.

Comment: @gelcode - unclear from your question what exactly you need. but if you have localsystem token - all is easy and possible

Comment: @ErykSun, Are you suggesting that, I start the application under the privileges of the interactive user (ie., the Standard User)

Comment: No, and I don't follow how you come to think that. I suggested duplicating a SYSTEM token, changing its session, and using that token to create the child process.

Comment: @ErykSun I have made certain changes to the code which I think attempts to do what you had suggested. But I end up with an ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.

Comment: At first glance, you can't call `DuplicateTokenEx` on the pseudohandle returned by [`GetCurrentProcessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocesstoken). It's only intended for querying information about an access token. This is documented behavior. Call `OpenProcessToken` with `TOKEN_DUPLICATE` access.